# What does "expanded to the mean, max, min, diff and relative diff" mean?

Tags: normal-distribution, dataset, normalization

I'm trying to work with a clinical dataset, where lab values and such don´t appear as they are measured, but this way:

```
PH_VENOUS_MEDIAN 0.3636363636363633
PH_VENOUS_MEAN 0.3636363636363633
PH_VENOUS_MIN 0.3636363636363633
PH_VENOUS_MAX 0.3636363636363633
PH_VENOUS_DIFF -1.0
```

According to the owners of the dataset: expanded to the mean, max, min, diff and relative diff. This example is a single window of time for a patient, there are 5 windows of time for each patient on the dataset

How should I interpret this? I would understand it if it were presented as X Std deviations from the mean, but now I'm kinda lost. For the record, the normal venous pH is 7.31-7.41

Comment: Are you asking why the pH are so low, or what the median means, or do you want to convert them to some other metric which you are more familiar with?

Comment: @mdewey I want to know what to think of this, as in, what does it mean.  How would one arrive at those values from a pH measure?